# Misrendered character in Debian/Xfce terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, text-rendering, xfce

I have an older desktop running Debian Stable with Xfce as the window manager. It's been working fine, except that as of today the character U (only uppercase) is shown as a filled block similar to █. This is the case in the terminal and in gedit windows, but not in other programs such as the file manager, LibreOffice, PDF viewers, or web browsers. There is also no display problem when I shift to a terminal outside the window manager with CTRL+ALT+F1. Any ideas how to go about diagnosing and fixing this?

Comment: Corrupted font file?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable hypothesis. How would I find/replace it?

Comment: What terminal do you use? Does it have a GUI or config file where you can check the font used?

Comment: It's GNOME Terminal 3.14.1. `tty` gives `/dev/pts/0`. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name` gives `'Monospace 20'`

Comment: Interestingly, other font sizes such as `Monospace 19` render fine, so using that as a workaround for now. I'd like to figure out what the problem is though so it doesn't spread.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the system? (I know...)

Comment: restarting does fix the problem, although I'm still curious about it

Comment: probably a memory corruption.

Comment: There seems to be an wider issue with some gnome related fonts scrolling through the interwebz.